# how to dynamically sum cells at different positions from multiple sheets in Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, sum

I have multiple sheets (representing months) that consist of number of hours a certain person does in a certain area. I'm trying to find a formula that searches the person(over time persons may be added or deleted, so their position will change in the next sheets) in all the sheets and sums all their hours in that area.

How the tables would look:

[image]

Comment: The formula will as long as sheet number increase. Better try to aggregate all data to a master sheet from all sheet then use formula to make summery.

Comment: That won't be possible because the months get added dynamically as they start and there are some calculations that need to be made on the sheets individually so, agregation is not possible

Comment: Then you have to go for `VBA` procedure.

Comment: I was looking for a simpler way to do it straight in excel, maybe using a vlookup or index-match, I just can't figure how to do it dynamically

Comment: Agree about aggregation. Robust solution is to aggregate into a database. When doing that, programmers know how to design the tables (and restrict flexibility of input) so that aggregation is possible.  The flexibility of the Excel GUI often blocks structured thinking.

Comment: I agree, your suggestion would be the best approach however, let say that I work for a company that, for somebody in my position, limits access to anything but this, would there be a way to do it without aggregating it  in a database?